# Cliente Java via Telnet

Tags: java, telnet

Buenas, estoy desarrollando un cliente java para que se conecte con un servidor Unix vía Telnet, me conecta bien sin problemas acepta comandos y todo, pero a la hora de imprimir el menú en pantalla no reconoce la configuración vt100 para ordenar la pantalla. Alguien tiene alguna idea? Estoy usando la librería commons-net

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) no implementa la gestión y composición de pantallas haciendo uso de códigos de control de terminal como `vt100` aunque te permita, por defecto, negociar dicho protocolo.

Deberás interpretar los códigos de control tú mismo, pero implementarlos no es trivial y probablemente no te interese empezar de cero la tarea.

Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a las siguientes aplicaciones Java que implementan dicho protocolo:

- https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm
- https://github.com/jcraft/jcterm
- https://github.com/grahamedgecombe/jterminal

Comment: Gracias Oscar, lo solucione, una vez accediendo al entorno Unix, exporter el termino TER=VT100. Y ahora funciona de maravilla.

Comment: Una preguntita si sabes, tenes idea si es posible recibir el stream via telnet y en vez de trabajar en linea de comando, pasarlo y trabajarlo por medio de java swing

Comment: Quizá quisiste decir `export TERM=VT100` (te faltó una M). Si te funciona simplemente cambiando eso es porque estás usando Linux, MacOS o en general un terminal de línea de comandos que soporta `vt100`. Que yo recuerde el símbolo de sistema de Windows no lo soporta. Echa un vistazo a mi edición para más que usan swing.

Comment: Jaja si me comí una M. Una vez que corrí mi jar desde consola Windows, ingrese vía Telnet al servidor Unix al cual me estoy conectando. Luego de loguearme, ahi puse: TERM=VT100;export TERM. Y funcionó